# what is new "[," means from some document?

Tags: javascript

I saw a a lot of explanation from different document like

```
new RegExp(pattern[, flags])
```

My question is, what is "[, flags]" means? why need "["?

can someone explain this to me, thanks.

Comment: Possible Optional parameter ?

Comment: it is a part of a [Backus-Naur-Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) for optional items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the argument `flags` is optional aka not necessary. That you can either create `RegExp` with one argument (`pattern`) or two arguments (`pattern` and `flags`).

Optional arguments often have default behavior when they're not provided, which is specified in the doc as "when xx is omitted", "when xx is undefined", "the default value for xx is ...".

Check out the [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method of `Array` for a prime example of this.